# How to check if two arrays are mirror images of each other in C?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, boolean

I am trying to see how to use C to check if two 2d arrays are symmetrical/mirror to each other.

So for example, if

```
array1 = { { 2, 5, 10 }, { 2, 1, 9 } };
array2 = { { 10, 5, 2 }, { 9, 1, 2 } };
```

The arrays are really 2d arrays.

How should I approach this?  So far I tried to read both 2d arrays and use if/else statements and a bool to check if both arrays are equal to each other or not. But I'm not sure how to check if they are mirror matrices of each other or not.

```
2 5 10  |  10 5 2
2 1  9  |   9 1 2
```

The compiler is from 89.

Comment: Traverse the arrays in parallel, one in ascending order, the other in reverse. And compare. Easy.

Comment: in one array use **i** as index and the onther one **n-i-1** where n is the lenght of both of them

Comment: those look like 1d arrays to me. Also recommend using a more recent (version of your) compiler.

Comment: There are many versions of gcc based on c89, c99, c11, etc. not just the one.

Comment: im running the code on visual studio. It should work fine in visual studio. but I have to test the code on c89 compiler from our university before submitting our work.

Comment: If your U is requiring to use gcc, I would warmly suggest to ditch VS right now.

Comment: GCC has had near-complete C99 support since the 3.0-3.1 era (2001-2002). MSVC has had semi-reasonable C99 support since 2013ish.

Comment: then my suggestion applies to your university :) But no `bool` is fine, just use `int`s. 0 is false, everything else is true.

Comment: "So far I tried to read both 2d arrays and use if/else statements and  ..."  Post that code.

Comment: So.. in the edited version, they should be mirrored *coumnwise*?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I am making assumptions based on what the OP tried to do with their raw text in their post. The mirror'd text table is what I think they are trying to detect in code, but this post is probably not salvageable without the OP providing the code for their attempt.

Comment: The first nested loop used to scan the first array: `for (a = 0; b < row; i++)` --> `for (a = 0; a < row; a++)`

Comment: Have you copy pasted the code in your question from different functions? Right now, you are declaring `array_1` and `array_2`, filling `first_array` and `second_array` and checking `m1` and `m2`... Pick up one name or better split your code into more functions.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to read values to both matrices the same way (hint 1: use functions). So they will both look like this:

First one:

```
{{m1[0][0], m1[0][1], m1[0][2],..., m1[0][99]},
 {m1[1][0], m1[1][1], m1[1][2],..., m1[1][99]},
 ...
 {m1[99][0], m1[99][1], ..., m1[99][99]}}
```

second one:

```
{{m2[0][0], m2[0][1], m2[0][2],..., m2[0][99]},
 {m2[1][0], m2[1][1], m2[1][2],..., m2[1][100]},
 ...
 {m2[99][0], m2[99][1], ..., m2[99][99]}}
```

But you have an error in first loop of reading m1 array:

```
for (a = 0; b < row; i++)
```

And then inside your comparison loop, you have :

```
m1[row][col] != m2[row][col]
```

Which compares values of both matrices with the same indices. So instead of comparing `m1[0][0]` with `m2[0][99]` you are comparing `m1[0][0]` with `m2[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define size 3

int main (void){
    int i,j,k,flag=1;
    int array1[][size] = { { 2, 5, 10},{ 2, 1, 9 } }, array2[][size] = { {10, 5, 2 }, { 9, 1, 2 } };

    //Check mirror image or not
    for(i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
        for(j=0,k=size-1;j<size;j++,k--) {
            if(array1[i][j]!=array2[i][k]) {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag)
        printf("Mirror image to each other");
    else
        printf("Not a mirror image to each other");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I need to use it for both 2d and 3d matrixes but I understand how to start the for-loops so I should be fine now. Thanks. Btw, why is it necessary for size to be a constant?

Comment: There is no constraint on size to be a constant. you can take size at runtime also.

Comment: Why do you need a `tmp` array?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify this property with 2 nested loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLS 3
#define ROWS 2

int main(void) {
    int array1[ROWS][COLS] = { { 2, 5, 10 }, { 2, 1, 9 } };
    int array2[ROWS][COLS] = { { 10, 5, 2 }, { 9, 1, 2 } };
    int xmirror = 1;
    int ymirror = 1;
    int xymirror = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            if (array1[i][j] != array2[i][COLS - 1 - j])
                xmirror = 0;
            if (array1[i][j] != array2[ROWS - 1 - i][j])
                ymirror = 0;
            if (array1[i][j] != array2[ROWS - 1 - i][COLS - 1 - j])
                xymirror = 0;
        }
    }
    if (xymirror)
        printf("Mirror image to each other rowwise and columnwise\n");
    if (ymirror)
        printf("Mirror image to each other rowwise\n");
    if (xmirror)
        printf("Mirror image to each other columnwise\n");
    if (xmirror + ymirror + xymirror == 0)
        printf("Not a mirror image of each other\n");
    return 0;
}
```